# Makefile Vpath multiple src Directories

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

I have a directory structure like

```
edited/
    Betrayal/
        index.md
    Bloodlines/
        cover.jpg
        index.md
    ...
```

and a Makefile like

```
PANDOC      := pandoc
PANDOC_OPTS := -t epub --smart --toc
EBOOK_CONVERT := ebook-convert

MODULES   := Betrayal Bloodlines Tempest Exile Sacrifice Inferno Fury Revelation Invincible
SRC_DIR   := $(addprefix edited/,$(MODULES))
BUILD_DIR := $(addprefix build/,$(MODULES))

SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.md))
EPUB      := $(patsubst edited/%.md,build/%.epub,$(SRC))
MOBI      := $(patsubst edited/%.md,build/%.mobi,$(SRC))

vpath %.md $(SRC_DIR)

define make-epub
$1/%.epub: %.md
    $(PANDOC) $(PANDOC_OPTS) $$< -o $$@
endef

define make-mobi
$1/%.mobi: $1/%.epub
    $(EBOOK_CONVERT) $$< $$@ >/dev/null
endef

.PHONY: all epubs mobis checkdirs clean

all: checkdirs mobis

epubs: $(EPUB)

mobis: $(MOBI)

checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rfv $(BUILD_DIR)

$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-epub,$(bdir))))

$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-mobi,$(bdir))))
```

(I still haven't added conditionals to test for a cover and metadata or added emailing via mutt to kindle, but here comes the current issue)

The only problem is how every directory has an index.md and the VPATH method will always pull the index from the first module ex

```
pandoc -t epub --smart --toc edited/Betrayal/index.md -o build/Betrayal/index.epub
pandoc -t epub --smart --toc edited/Betrayal/index.md -o build/Bloodlines/index.epub
pandoc -t epub --smart --toc edited/Betrayal/index.md -o build/Tempest/index.epub
pandoc -t epub --smart --toc edited/Betrayal/index.md -o build/Exile/index.epub
...
```

I could rename each index.md to the unique name of each folder like `(for d in *; do echo "$d"; cd "$d"; mv index.md "$d".md; cd ..; done)` and everything would work fine, but I want to learn makefile syntax and there must be a more elegant way to handle src directories without tons of recursive makefiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without the rule templates and `foreach` constructions altogether. Remember that a wildcard can match a large part of a path:

```
build/%.epub: edited/%.md
    $(PANDOC) $(PANDOC_OPTS) $< -o $@

build/%.mobi: build/%.epub
    $(EBOOK_CONVERT) $< $@ >/dev/null
```

Comment: Wow. Guess I was really overthinking it. Thanks